# What does it mean to cancel a burn card?

Tags: titanfall

What does it mean when you cancel a burn card? I sometimes see the XP bonus: *BURN CARD CANCELLED*. What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you just a killed pilot who had a Burn Card active.

Each round you can carry in up to 3 **Burn Cards**, selected before the map loads:

- You can choose to activate 1 card each time before you spawn, selected while waiting to start or respawn.
- Just 1 card can be active at a time.
- When the match ends any active card is cancelled.
- If you die any active card is cancelled.
- Some burn cards have a one time effect (for instance reducing the time to next titanfall). These are applied immediately and then lost.
- If another pilot kills you *and* you have an active card they get a **Burn Card Cancelled** bonus.
- If you kill another pilot and they have an active card you get a **Burn Card Cancelled** bonus.
- Burn Cards don't time out - you have have one active card for an entire match (from beginning to end) if you don't die.
- **Burn Card Cancelled** bonuses are awarded at the same time as the XP for killing the pilot who had it.

Note that this goes for titan related cards - even if the card only boosts a player's titan they won't lose the card. If they survive until they can drop another titan they still have it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you have to get the kill within a specific time of them using the card?

Comment: @peper757 That's plenty specific - They had an active card and you killed them. I don't even play titanfall and I get what he's saying

Comment: @chipperyman573 Not really. There appears to be a time limit, which is what I am now asking him.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I'd imagine until the burn card runs out.

Comment: @peper757 there's no time limit. If they have a Burn Card active and you kill them you get the XP for cancelling it. Burn Cards don't expire by time - they last until you die or the match ends. If another player kills you and you have a Burn Card active _they_ get the cancel bonus.

Comment: @chipperyman573 Burn Cards don't run out - I've carried one right through a match (an amped sniper rifle, I spend the match camping from the edge of the map). They always last until the match ends or you die. In games with rounds (for instance in Last Titan Standing) they carry across, if you survive.

Comment: Some Burn cards are one-time effects like X seconds off titan build time, most are swapping weapons that last til the end of your life.

Comment: @Keith You should update your answer with that.

Comment: @peper757 I have done.